# JSON insert records into Salesforce

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest, salesforce

Hi this is a long shot but I'm attempting to insert data into a sales-force Object through an API call from PHP(Codeigniter framework). I am using CURL protocol and the record is  not being inserted but I receive no error message either.

All my parameters for connection are correct and I get retrieve records/update records successfully but I cannot insert.

```
public function insert_record($object_name, $field_list=FALSE) {

    $request = trim($this->instance_url).
    '/services/data/'.$this->api_version.'/sobjects/'.trim($object_name).'/';
    return $this->execute_request($request, FALSE , json_encode($field_list));
}
```

### The function call:

```
$record_to_insert = array("Name__c" => 
"Ricky Hernadez", "Status__c" => "Single", 
"Description__c" => "This is a test");


$this->data['results'] =$results = $this->salesforce->insert_record("Online_Participant__c", $record_to_insert);
```

> 

### this is what $results array contains:

```
object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
  ["recentItems"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#25 (3) {
      ["attributes"]=>
      object(stdClass)#26 (2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(21) "Online_Participant__c"
        ["url"]=>
        string(70) "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Online_Participant__c/a0bi00000027HGbAAM"
      }
      ["Id"]=>
      string(18) "a0bi00000027HGbAAM"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(6) "OP0004"
    }
  }
  ["objectDescribe"]=>
  object(stdClass)#27 (21) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "Online_Participant__c"
    ["label"]=>
    string(18) "Online Participant"
    ["keyPrefix"]=>
    string(3) "a0b"
    ["labelPlural"]=>
    string(19) "Online Participants"
    ["custom"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["layoutable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["activateable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["urls"]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (3) {
      ["sobject"]=>
      string(51) "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Online_Participant__c"
      ["describe"]=>
      string(60) "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Online_Participant__c/describe"
      ["rowTemplate"]=>
      string(56) "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Online_Participant__c/{ID}"
    }
    ["searchable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["deprecatedAndHidden"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["createable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["updateable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["deletable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["customSetting"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["feedEnabled"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["mergeable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["queryable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["replicateable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["retrieveable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["undeletable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["triggerable"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: You sure it failed? Your response seems to contain both the generated id (`a0bi00000027HGbAAM`), Name and URL you can use to fetch data via REST (`/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Online_Participant__c/a0bi00000027HGbAAM`)... Go to `https://instance.salesforce.com/a0bi00000027HGbAAM`? Also - which HTTP verb do you use? Should be POST for insert, PATCH for update, GET for retrieve etc.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be making a GET request, you need to use POST to create a new record.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use the Force.com PHP Toolkit because you will avoid this kind of problems.

You can download it from here:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

Sample code:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples

Comment: The Force.com PHP Toolkit is out of date. I could not get it to work to update data into Salesforce.